# Set the status field in the changes

Tags: gerrit

`Gerrit Version - 2.16.17` and DB is `MYSQL-5.7`.

Error 500 occurred during the `Sumit` time in Gerrit UI. But the changes have been merged. We can see them in our git repository, but the status in the Gerrit UI is not correct (Ie:  it is displaying "Submit including parents" instead of "merged".

Have tried indexing changes and this particular project indexing as well. But unfortunately couldn't help.

Now is there a way to `Set` the status field in the changes to `Merged` at backend to maintain the review history?

Any advice to solve this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you clicked on the "Submit including parents" button? What did happen?

Comment: Yes I have clicked it. But option is in disabled mode.

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are trying to resolve? The changes have been merged since you can see them in your git repository, but the status in the UI is not correct (i.e.: it is displaying "Submit including parents" instead of "merged")?

Comment: @barbasa, Yes correct.

Comment: You said you manually reindex the changes, did you check in the `<your_gerrit_path>/logs/error_logs` if the indexing of the changes or the whole project were successful or if there was any error?

Comment: Changes and single project manual index successfully finished. But in UI still shows `Submit including parents` and `Submit`(Button showing in disabled mode). In `error_log` file cannot see any errors for two actions.